# RecycleView click, showing message: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase

the wrong messsage is " Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference". what I am trying to do is clicking one item on recycleView and jump to another page. the code is below:

```
public contactHolder(View itemView, Activity context) {
    super(itemView);
    this.context = context;

    Fname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.getFname);
    Lname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.getLname);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startAnew(contactID);
        }
    });

}
private void startAnew(String currentcontactID) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, personActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(CONTACT_ID,currentcontactID);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: You passed a null context into the constructor

Comment: Not really clear why you're passing the Activity to the ViewHolder https://stackoverflow.com/q/37186805/2308683