# I am working with RecyclerView and CardView

Tags: android

How am I suppose to go to different activities respectively after I click each of the Images above like If I click Honeycomb i would go to Honeycomb class and when i click on Eclair, I would go to eclair class and so on.

Comment: Where is your image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need more details for your question, but in general, if you want to go from one activity to different activity by selecting different images you can use Recycler View and set onClickListner on images in adapter class and set action startActivity(intent) according to image position. for more details about Recycler View and its implementation, check this link- http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: I am designing a message Receiving feature for my app..interface have been done with RecyclerView and CardView.. for the time being i used image and name here.. so when i click on listed item, i want the item to show in other activity.

Comment: you can impliment onClicklistner in you bindview holder method and pass your item through intent and start new activity.

Comment: check this link for more details-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767413/how-to-open-a-different-activity-on-recyclerview-item-onclick