# how to pass the value from one activity to another by using Context and output is to be seen in another actitvity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

**when i click on the text the app crashes and error appears in the line below mentioned.**

```
public class DataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView table;
    int tableData;

    public DataHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        table = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.table_list);

        table.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("ashu", "onClick: is called");
                tableData = Integer.parseInt(table.getText().toString());

                Context context = view.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, RecyclerAdapterNew.class);

                intent.putExtra("transfer", tableData);
                Log.d("ashu", "last lone is to be executed");

                context.startActivity(intent);//error in this line
            }
        });



    }


}
```

**my second class is this in which i have to pass the value through the
putExtra but the app crashes in the previous Activity when i click my text**

```
public class RecyclerAdapterNew extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataHolderNew> {

    int tableData;


    @Override
    public DataHolderNew onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_values, parent, false);

        Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
        tableData = intent.getIntExtra("transfer", tableData);

        return new DataHolderNew(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataHolderNew holder, int position) {

        holder.table_value.setText((position + 1) * tableData);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }

}
```

Comment: make publc Context con;  and pass Context from your hosting activity to recyclerview adapter. and then use it

Comment: i am not clear by your point?

Comment: try using only startActivity(intent);

Comment: not working this way

Comment: Pass superclass context to adapter through constructor and use that context in the adapter and viewholder.

Comment: You have to use Activity context for first parameter of startActivity() method.
You can do this in 2 ways. 1- using interface(recommend): when an item in RecyclerView clicks send data of current item to host activity by interface 2- Add an context parameter for constructor of your adapter and send host activity to this parameter then save it in a field.

Comment: Can you set your onclicklistener in the onbindviewholder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a different activity on recyclerView item onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767413/how-to-open-a-different-activity-on-recyclerview-item-onclick)