# Can I use startActivity in onCreateViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I make a onClick in recyclerView onCreateViewHolder like this.

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_homeinfo, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), Integer.toString(holder.getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return holder;
    }
```

and I want to put this code in onClick.

```
final String serverURL = "http://youngh.cafe24app.com/qrock/views/qrock_pk/user_email";

                myDb = new DatabaseHelper(v.getContext());  //is it Possible?
                final String token = myDb.getToken();
                final String email = myDb.getEmail();

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, serverURL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), mainActivity.class);   //v.getContent() <- ERROR
                                startActivity(myIntent);
                                finish();

                                overridePendingTransition(R.xml.madefadein, R.xml.splashfadeout);
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        switch(error.networkResponse.statusCode)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        //params.put("qrock_pk", qrockPk);
                        params.put("user_email", email);
                        return params;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                        headers.put("x-access-token", token);
                        return headers;
                    }
                };
                MySingleton.getInstance(v.getContext()).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);
```

But in onCreateViewHolder, I can't cast `startActivity()`, `finish()` etc.
I want to make when I click a recyclerViewItem, start these code and move to another activity. How to use these code???

I'm sorry I can not speak English well.

Comment: You need to pass context to use startActivity(), finish(). so whenever you want to use startActivity() it is call like this context.startActivity().
Yes you can use this code on onClick()

Comment: Use context and cast and cast context to Activity like this:Activity activity = (Activity) context;

Comment: refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767413/how-to-open-a-different-activity-on-recyclerview-item-onclick

Comment: You could also make a callback to the activity that holds the adapter and launch from there. Or better yet trigger an event that the parent activity subscribes to and launch accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

In `onCreateViewHolder`:

```
context = v.getContext()
```

Then go on and use `context.startActivity()` and  `((Activity)context).finish();`

Comment: Can you try with  ((Activity)context).finish();

Comment: It works! but Can I declare `DatabaseHelper myDb;` in homeAdapter? and I want to use myDb like this `myDb = new DatabaseHelper(v.getContext()); ` Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Intent myIntent= new Intent(v.getContext(), mainActivity.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this;

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mainActivity.class);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: starting an activity from application context would require specifics flags like FLAG_NEW_TASK

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `onCreateViewHolder` do the click function `onBindViewHolder`. The reason is `onBindViewHolder` is called everytime add `onCreateViewHolder` is called only while creating views.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //use holder.itemView.getContext() to get context
            Toast.makeText( holder.itemView.getContext().getContext(), Integer.toString(holder.getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll move it

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this         ((Activity)ctx).startActivity();

Comment: where ctx is context

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change getContext() to view.getContext();

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class));    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. onCreateViewHolder**

Here you have to do create/initialize your views

**2. onBindViewHolder**

Here you have to do logics, bind the views , on click actions