# If I click on Recycler view then how to go for a new activity?

Tags: android

My code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),Watch.class);
    startactivity(i);
}
```

If I click on Recycler view then how to go for a new activity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a different activity on recyclerView item onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767413/how-to-open-a-different-activity-on-recyclerview-item-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this, you have to make listener from your adapter to your activity,[Read this document](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Watch.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please search out the solutions before posting such basic questions, it has already been answered in the past. I have marked this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily by making the inner viewholder class implement the OnClickListenerInterface and then setting up a listener for clicks in your activity/fragment.

```
class BluetoothAdapter(var bluetoothDevices:ArrayList<BluetoothDevice?>,var mListener:BluetoothDeviceViewHolder.OnBluetoothDeviceClicked):

RecyclerView.Adapter<BluetoothAdapter.BluetoothDeviceViewHolder>() {

 class BluetoothDeviceViewHolder(itemView: View,var listener: OnBluetoothDeviceClicked,var bluetoothDevices: ArrayList<BluetoothDevice?>) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),View.OnClickListener {

    var name= itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.bluetoothDeviceName)
     init {
         itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
     }
     interface OnBluetoothDeviceClicked{
         fun onBluetoothDeviceClicked(bluetoothDevice: BluetoothDevice?)
     }

     override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        listener.onBluetoothDeviceClicked(bluetoothDevices[adapterPosition])
    }

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BluetoothDeviceViewHolder {
   return BluetoothDeviceViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false),mListener,this.bluetoothDevices)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return bluetoothDevices.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BluetoothDeviceViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.name.text =  bluetoothDevices[position]?.name

}
```

Your activity will look something like this

```
class SendAndReceiveActivity : AppCompatActivity() ,BluetoothService.OnBluetoothEventCallback {
override fun onBluetoothDeviceClicked(bluetoothDevice: BluetoothDevice?) {

    var intent:Intent = Intent(this,Xyz::class.java)//This line will 
   //start a 
   // new activity when something is clicked in recycler view



}
```

}